# EOF adds to counter, no idea why

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have been stuck trying to understand why triggering `eof` using ctrl-D adds to a counter in a `for` loop.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; nc++){
       getchar();
    }
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

My outcome is :

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

The `8` is what's given to me when I use ctrl-D after inputting `7`. Is there a reason why triggering the `eof` causes the code to run another complete loop? 
I thought an empty buffer will return nothing.

Comment: You're calling `getchar` twice per iteration. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Why `double`????

Comment: As @Quentin said, you call `getchar` twice. If you want it to stop when you press Ctrl+D, remove the body of the cycle.

Comment: I propose to close this thread, it makes no sense, too broad.

Comment: @xing oh. The formatting of the question was broken so I didn't see the newlines.

Comment: @Quentin I added that second getchar to eat up a newline because without it the counter goes up by 2 instead of 1. I can't seem to make my counter go up by one properly.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The double was for practice from the code exercise. I left it thinking it won't change much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you might miss. Take piece of your code:

```
for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; nc++)
    getchar();
```

There are two `getchar()`. Let's call them, `getchar1()` and `getchar2()`. Your input should be like this:

```
0\n
.
.
.
7\n
EOF
```

`getchar1()` catch the sequence of digits and `EOF`. `getchar2()` always catch the newline ('\n'). And the count of you go through for loop body is 8 (0 to 7).

Hope it helpful for you.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand that. What gets me is when I get rid of the second getchar(), the counter goes up by 2 instead of one so I added that second getchar() to stop the second iteration. Is there an alternative way to make the counter go up by one? Oddly enough, the counter works fine if I don't use eof as the conditional for the for loop.

Comment: I don't sure you want to count **num of string** or **num of char except for newline**. With counting num of char except for newline, you can do it by `while (1) switch (getchar()) {case '\n': continue; case EOF: break; default: nc++;}`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was completing an exercise for finding the number of characters and this is what I was also looking for. I'm pretty new to C so I have never seen the switch statement before and will help with my problem.